# Unique Absolute MySQL Value

Tags: mysql

I have a database with the integer `id` that can be positive or negative. However a positive and negative integer with the same absolute value can't exist.

Is it possible to set up a key that would ensure `id`'s absolute value uniqueness?

The following attempt returns a syntax error:

```
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD KEY(ABS(`id`));
```

Comment: what does `select version();` show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add virtual generated column into the table structure and uniquely index it.

```
ALTER TABLE tablename
    ADD COLUMN abs_id INT AS (ABS(id)) VIRTUAL,
    ADD UNIQUE INDEX (abs_id));
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6b44ddc1085318b447ac70d2cbc9fb55)